# If I already have linux installed, if i resize my main partition and install windows 10, will i still be able to boot linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10

Like I said in the title if I already have Linux installed, and I resize my home partition and install windows 10, will the windows boot manager detect my Linux installation? Or will the installer detect the currently installed bootloader and skip the installation of the windows boot manager?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will indeed be ignored, It will instantly boot to linux.

Very detailed information can be found here.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu